# PHP insert into is failing to insert into mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to insert value(s) of a input textfield into mysql database with no avail!

what I am trying to do is to enter the `product_name` value(s) into `product_name` column in the `transactions` table!

I don't understand what is preventing the INSERT INTO to execute!

Could someone please take a look at this and let me know what is wrong?

I don't even get any errors so I don't know what is wrong!

```
<form action="order.php" method="post" name="shoppingcart">
    <?php 
    //We want to include the shopping cart in the email
    ob_start();
    ?>
    <table style="border-collapse:collapse;" width="100%" border="1">
      <tr>
        <th style="border-collapse:collapse;" scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
        <th scope="col">Item Name</th>
        <th scope="col">Unit Price</th>
        <th scope="col">Qty</th>
        <th scope="col">Cost</th>
      </tr>

        <?php 
        //Print all the items in the shopping cart
        // First we check to see if the form has been submitted 

   $totalAll = 0;
   $total = 0;
   $ship = $_POST['ship'];
    foreach ($_SESSION['SHOPPING_CART'] as $itemNumber => $item) {
if (isset($_POST['username'])){
    //Connect to the database through our include 
    include_once "config/connect.php";      

        // Add user info into the database table, claim your fields then values
        $sql = "INSERT INTO transactions (firstname, lastname, username, email, price, qty, product_name) 
        VALUES('$firstname','$lastname','$username','$email','$price','$qty','$product_name')" or die;
        $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
        // Get the inserted ID here to use in the activation email
        $id = mysqli_insert_id($db_conx);
} 

    $totalAll = $totalAll + ($item['qty']*$item['price']);

    $total = $totalAll + $ship;
        ?>
        <tr id="item<?php echo $itemNumber; ?>">    
            <td><a href="order.php?remove=<?php echo $itemNumber; ?>">remove</a></td>
            <td><?php echo $item['name']; ?></td>
            <td>£<?php echo $item['price']; ?></td>
            <td><input name="items_qty[<?php echo $itemNumber; ?>]" type="text" id="item<?php echo $itemNumber; ?>_qty" value="<?php echo $item['qty']; ?>" size="2" maxlength="3" /></td>
            <td>£<?php echo $item['qty'] * $item['price']; ?></td> 
            <input name="price" type="hidden" id="" value="<?php echo $item['price']; ?>" size="2" maxlength="10" />
    <input name="qty" type="hidden" id="" value="<?php echo $item['qty']; ?>" size="2" maxlength="10" />
    <input name="product_name" type="txt" id="" value="<?php echo $item['name']; ?>" size="2" maxlength="10" />     
        </tr>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
    </table>
    </div>
            <?php $_SESSION['SHOPPING_CART_HTML'] = ob_get_flush(); ?>
```

Comment: did u check echo $sql; if all the values are there in the insert or by using mysqli errors ?

Comment: Have you even populated the variables you're using in `VALUES`?

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty, I'm not entirely sure what you mean?

Comment: @Ryan, I've added `$product_name = $_POST['product_name'];` at the top of the code and still doesn't INSERT the `product_name` value into the mysql database!

Comment: `echo mysqli_error($db_conx)`.

Comment: @MichaelRushton, I've already got `<?php 
// Script Error Reporting
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
?>` in my page! I did your error reporting code as well and still no errors!

Comment: Is `$_SESSION['SHOPPING_CART']` empty? Is `$_POST['username']` set? And just to clarify, you *did* add `mysqli_error($db_conx)` below `$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql)`, right?

Comment: @MichaelRushton, The  `$_SESSION['SHOPPING_CART']` is not empty and `$_POST['username']` is set as it will parse all other values to the mysql database i.e. the `email` and `username` and `email` etc... it will only leave the values of `product_name`, `qty` and `price` empty for some reason! and yes i've put the error reporting right under the query..

Comment: And do `$product_name`, `$qty` and `$price` actually have any values?

Comment: @MichaelRushton, Yes, they do! `<input name="product_name" type="txt" id="" value="<?php echo $item['name']; ?>" size="2" maxlength="10" />` and i actually see the product_name echo'ed in the input textfield.

Comment: Try `echo`ing the `$sql` query.